# List of escape characters for several languages

Tags: language-agnostic, escaping

This [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) article features at the bottom a broken link to a [Escape characters in 9 languages](http://codecodex.com/wiki/Escape_sequences_and_escape_characters) page that looks promising. I'm looking for a comprehensive list of languages with their respective escape characters.

This if for a document-generation-from-template feature I'm working on. Since it is a general purpose document generation, it would be nice to have a list of escaping functions that can be used when generating pieces of the document, such as ToXmlAttribute, ToXmlText, ToHtmlText and so on.

Does anyone know such a list, or the closest possible thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the most recent [wayback machine link](http://web.archive.org/web/20101228015850/http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Escape_sequences_and_escape_characters) for that article.